# Display model popup with chancel button when user put more than 10% of amount in first textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint-2013

For example

My first text box is Current Rate

```
< asp.TextBox  ID="CurrentRateTextBox" runat="server".asp>
```

My second textbox is New pay rate

```
<asp.TextBox  ID="NewPayRateTextBox" runat="server".asp>
```

If user put amount in CurrentRateTextBox (lets say he put $100)

So When user put the amount in NewPayRateTexbox, if user puts more than 10% increase of CurrentRateTextBox (let say he puts $120 on NewPayRateTexbox) Then modelpopup should show up with cancel button.

else user puts less than $110 in NewPayRateTextBox then There will no any exception. I am completely beginner and developing in WebPart. Thank you

Comment: I am trying to do this jQuery and i used this from some other example

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: $("#"+newPayRateID).on('focusout', function () {

  var currRate = $("[id$="+currRateVal).attr("id");
  var currVal = $("#"+currRate).val();
   //alert(currVal);
   var percentVal = parseFloat(currVal) * 0.1;
   var newCheckVar = percentVal + currVal;
   alert(newCheckVar);
   if(newPayVal > newCheckVar)
    $("#"+newPayRateID).css("border","1px solid Red");
 });

Comment: I used this to give ID ---------

var currRate = $("[id$="+currRateVal).attr("id");
  var currVal = $("#"+currRate).val();

Comment: Can you update the question? so it's easier to read?

Comment: Thanks  JanR. Finally able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write something like below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
        var num1 = document.getElementById("CurrentRateTextBox").value;
        var num2 = document.getElementById("NewPayRateTextBox").value;

        var inc = ((num2 - num1) / num1 * 100);
        alert(inc);
        if (inc >= 10)
        {
            //your code
            document.getElementById("NewPayRateTextBox").value = "";

        } else { }

    }

</script>
```

approach to call

```
ID="NewPayRateTextBox" onblur="myFunction()"
```